# How to read dynamic/changing keys from JSON in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am using the UK Bus API to collect bus arrival times etc.

In Python 3 I have been using....

```
try:
    connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection("transportapi.com")
    connection.request("GET", "/v3/uk/bus/stop/xxxxxxxxx/live.json?app_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&app_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&group=route&nextbuses=yes")

    res = connection.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    connection.close()

    from types import SimpleNamespace as Namespace
    x = json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda d: Namespace(**d))

    print("Stop Name : " + x.stop_name)
```

Which is all reasonably simple, however the JSON  data returned looks like this...

```
{
   "atcocode":"xxxxxxxx",
   "smscode":"xxxxxxxx",
   "request_time":"2020-03-10T15:42:22+00:00",
   "name":"Hospital",
   "stop_name":"Hospital",
   "bearing":"SE",
   "indicator":"adj",
   "locality":"Here",
   "location":{
      "type":"Point",
      "coordinates":[
         -1.xxxxx,
         50.xxxxx
      ]
   },
   "departures":{
      "8":[
         {
            "mode":"bus",
            "line":"8",
            "line_name":"8",
            "direction":"North",
            "operator":"CBLE",
            "date":"2020-03-10",
```

Under "departures" the key name changes due to the bus number / code.

Using Python 3 how do I extract the key name and all subsequent values below/within it?

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
for k,v in x["departures"].items():
    print(k,v) #or whatever else you wanted to do.
```

Which returns:

`8 [{'mode': 'bus', 'line': '8', 'line_name': '8', 'direction': 'North', 'operator': 'CBLE', 'date': '2020-03-10'}]`

So `k` is equal to 8 and `v` is the value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly I get "TypeError: 'types.SimpleNamespace' object is not subscriptable" for the for loop line. Any idea what it could be please?